# Spectral radius of discrete Laplacian

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius, graph-laplacian

We discretize the domain $\Omega = [0,1]^2$ with the step size $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n-1}$. Then, for the largest eigenvalue of the discrete Laplacian it holds

$$\lambda_{\max}(-\Delta)\leq 8(n-1)^2.$$

I tried to find a proof for that, but was not successful. Is there an explanation? Thanks!

---

Edit: the boundary condition for a solution $m$ is given by $\nu \cdot m = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $\nu$ is the normal field of $\Omega$.

Comment: Which boundary conditions do you use?

Comment: I have added it to the boundary condition to the post.

Comment: I don't understand how $\nu \cdot m$ makes sense, if $m$ is a solution then $m$ is just a scalar at each point.

Comment: In any case your discrete Laplacian is just a matrix, and it seems like this result is what you get when you apply Gerschgorin's theorem to the rows corresponding to interior points, since the diagonal entry of $-\Delta$ will be $4(n-1)^2$ and there will be four off-diagonal entries each given by $-(n-1)^2$. Do the boundary rows somehow spoil the result?

Comment: I dont know how to answer the question.  I dont know, how the result is affected

Comment: I thought that $\nu\cdot m$ on the boundary is okay. I thought, this is called "zero flow" BC. It comes from this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10915-017-0529-1

Comment: No, that's not going to be $\nu$ dotted with just $m$, that's going to be $\nu$ dotted with a "gradient". In any case I don't see why those rows would have an absolute row sum any larger than the interior ones, so yeah this should follow immediately from Gerschgorin's theorem once you actually write your matrix down.

Comment: Your boundary condition does not make sense... A solution, $u$, of the laplace equation is real valued, so $u \cdot \nu$ is hill defined. Most likely, your condition will be either $u=0$ or $\nabla u \cdot \nu =0$ on the boundary.

Comment: Also, the information you provide is not enough to actually define the discrete laplacian. You are probably assuming that the problem is being discretized using finite differences, but this must be stated at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using standard finite differences, you matrix will be "penta-diagonal" and Gerschgorin's theorem can give you an estimate of the spectral radius. Using the most populated rows, you can see that any eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies
$$
\left|\lambda + \frac{4}{h^2}\right|\leq \frac{4}{h^2}.
$$

So, you can conclude that $|\lambda| \leq 8(n-1)^2$ (I'm assuming the solution vanishes at the boundary).